# An adjective for gestalt

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Is there an adjective to describe someone  with the ability to quickly grasp/see the whole picture out of a few perceived details. This person is not detail-oriented and never fails to see the forest for the trees. Gestalt effect comes close to what I mean but I'm looking for an adjective.

Comment: For *gestalt*, the OED has derivatives only *gestaltism* and *gestaltist*.  It has no adjective like *gestaltic*.  But you could probably use that and be understood.

Comment: Perhaps _perspicacious_?

Comment: 'Visionary' would overlap with this, but it's an overworked word. 'Perceptive', 'discerning' and 'far-sighted' are synonyms.

Comment: @GEdgar gestaltic is good but I'm looking for a word that is not scientific.

Comment: [broad-visioned](https://www.google.ca/?gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&tbm=bks&q=%22broad-visioned%22)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Visionary should be made into an answer, it may be the closest thing out there to what the OP is seeking.  (Your other suggestions don't have the same implications of big picture as opposed to detail-oriented.)

Comment: @Chris Sunami Thank you. But I don't consider it close enough for an 'answer'. Sometimes, there just aren't any.

Comment: A narrowly focused question seeking a narrowly defined word that involves seeing the bigger picture. Ironic. Also, please take a look at [single-word-request wiki](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) info for four questions to answer for a good single word request.

Comment: ... *Sherlockian*?

Answer (score 2):

If your point is to contrast details with the whole picture I'd suggest

> holistic

This probably needs to be explicitly combined with "perception" to get the point across.

Comment: Holistic can't describe a person.

Answer (score 2):

You could describe him or her as a "*big-picture* thinker" or a "*big-picture* person."

Comment: I'm looking for a single word.

Answer (score 0):

One word that describes the ability to grasp and understand the entire situation is "grok" taken from Heinleins "Stranger in a strange land"

One who groks a problem or situation understands it deeply, all the way doen to the sub-atomic level.

Comment: OP definitely wants an adjective and _grok_'s a verb.

Comment: @tmgr 'grokalicious'?

Comment: @Mitch If you're a Turtle, maybe... in which case, Mitchelangelo? Otherwise I'd go _grokky_, seeing you're asking!